# Activity.Current is null on HttpRequestOut.Stop

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-application-insights, system.diagnostics, .net-core-2.1

I'm using Application Insights for Console App (.NET Core 2.1).

I need to gather more information about dependencies(requests/responses) than `ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector` does.

So I've tried the approach described in [this blog](https://geeklearning.io/application-insights-extensibility-tricks-worth-knowing-1-2/). And it works for requests.
But it does not work for responses. Because in the code above `Activity.Current` is `null`:

```
[DiagnosticName("System.Net.Http.HttpRequestOut.Stop")]
public virtual void OnHttpRequestOutStop(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response, TaskStatus requestTaskStatus)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Activity.Current);
}
```

While in the similar code for `HttpRequestOut.Start` it has proper value:

```
[DiagnosticName("System.Net.Http.HttpRequestOut.Start")]
public virtual void OnHttpRequestOutStart(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Activity.Current);
}
```

Why in `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestOut.Stop` event the `Activity.Current` is `null`?
How can I access the same activity in *Start* and *Stop* events?

*UPDATE*:
I've found some info about the issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/820#issuecomment-366381191).

Comment: Found the solution. Just make sure you initialized your observer before telemetryClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/820#issuecomment-366381191) really helped.

> The most complicated scenario is when you want to access response and enrich telemetry based on it. you can still use diagnostic source Stop event, however, this becomes hacky because AppInsights listens to the same even and your listener needs to receive the Stop event before AppInsights.

So I just initialized my 'enrichment' observer class before the telemetry client. And `Activity.Current` is no longer `null` in `OnHttpRequestOutStop`.

Comment: Maybe in future releases it will not be required. 
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/1038